# efficiently display total number of users and number of users currently on the application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails application how do you efficiently display the total number of users and current number of users online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sam,

There are many methods for tracking online users. For example, authlogic has a `last_request_at` column which tracks when they last made a request to the site. Though, it's not very efficient to run a query for that every page load. I personally use Redis for tracking that sort of activity.

Here is a great example: [Redis in practice, who is online](http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2010/01/17/redis-in-practice-whos-online/)

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to get the list of your online users is to store sessions in the DB (use ActiveRecord SessionStore), then retrieve recently updated sessions from the DB, deserialize them and see which users they belong to.